# How does String.format method work in java?

Tags: java, string, format

This method

```
String.format("%1$,.2f", new Double(123456789.1011))
```

returns 123,456,789.10

Whereas

```
String.format("%4$,.2f", new Double(123456789.1011))
```

gives java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException

can anyone explain what is happening and what does $ do in the above code?

Comment: Why are you using `$` if you don't know what it does?  Have you checked the docs?

Comment: Read the Fine Manual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the $ is the argument index: see "Argument Index" in [java-docs Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

```
String.format("%4$,.2f", new Double(123456789.1011))
```

your example fails, because you only provide one argument, but you try to access the 4th

Answer (score 1):

```
String.format("%2$s", 32, "Hello"); // prints: "Hello"
```

The integer before dollar selects the index of argument to select. Here it prints the second argument "Hello"
As you are specifying 4 and there is only one argument it will give you error.